# Closing/unbinding a UDP socket in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, udp

Is there a way I can force a UDP socket (***which is used by another process***) to close or unbind, in c# programmatically?

Comment: You could release the network connection (like ipconfig /release).. but I guess that isnt the answer you're looking for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you close that process.

Comment: I hoped there would be sth like SocketPool... :(